# Assign an Array element to Another Array

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, combobox, flex4

Hello I have this array:

```
private var all_array:Array = [
    { symbol: "ADBE", name: "Adobe Systems Inc.", price: 49.95 },
    { symbol: "MACR", name: "Macromedia Inc.", price: 39.95 },
    { symbol: "MSFT", name: "Microsoft Corp.", price: 25.95 },
    { symbol: "IBM", name: "IBM Corp.", price: 42.55 }
    ];
```

I want another array which takes the values of the price from the 1st Array.
Can we do something like this?

```
private var another_price_array:Array = [all_array.price];
```

This second array will be used to populate a ComboBox, or can I populate the combo directly from the first array itself?

Thanks

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MX ComboBox:

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{all_array}" labelField="price" />
```

Spark ComboBox:

```
<s:ComboBox = dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(all_array)}" labelField="price" />
```

To use this code without changes make sure your `all_array` is bindable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not populate the ComboBox directly w/ the First array?  You will need to turn it into an ArrayList or ArrayCollection if you're using Spark components, though:

Do something like this to turn your array into an ArrayCollection:

```
private var myCollection = new ARrayCollection(all_Array);
```

and set it as the dataProvider, specifying the labelField to display your price data in the drop down of the ComboBox:

```
<s:ComboBox dataProvider="{myCollection}" labelField="price" />
```

Comment: yes I think I didn't ask my question well..its more complicated than that..I will post a new question.